# Prolog - ODBC interface

Tags: stored-procedures, odbc, prolog, visual-prolog

I have a requirement like inserting a large data from visual prolog end to the oracle database and also most importantly all the data needs to be injected through a single stored procedure call. I have tried them passing the data as string values, but there is  a constraint in visual prolog like the length the string variable cannot exceed '250' characters. So passing them as strings is not viable for my requirement. so I tried passing the data in the form of prolog list using `term_str()`. But unfortunately the list/array item is not handled at the oracle end. My DBA has suggested me to pass the large data in the form of an array objects. 
Do anybody have an idea how to convert the array data into an array object in visual prolog. or any other recommendations for inserting the large data into database through a single stored procedure call??

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Visual Prolog, but for SWI there is a nice 
 [chapter in the manual on the ODBC](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%280,%270%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/odbc.html%27%29%29)